# Run a function if key in a for in loop has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Given the following code:

```
     for (var key in values) {
        if (values[key] === true) {
           console.log(key + " is true")

           // I want to run this if key has changed.
           $(".box3").append("<p>" + key + "</p>");

           $.getJSON("js/" + key + "/" + key + ".json", function(data) {
               console.log(data)

               $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        console.log(val)
               $("#whatToOrder2").append("<div class='box'>" + val.name.toUpperCase() + "<input type='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' value='0' name=" + val.name.replace(/\s/g, '') + " class='css-input2 input-form2' placeholder='Menge'>");

                    });
                });
            }

            else {
                console.log(key + " is false");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a loop which displays different boxes. Like Fungi, Without onions etc. 
Each box has a category in this example Pizza and Kebab Like you see in the image below.

[image]

My goal is to add a bar if the last element has loaded from this category. Then it should add the category bar to the DOM. So when the key (pizza, kebab) has changed i want to add an element to the DOM.

How can I archive this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `I want to run this if key has changed.` - it will change every iteration

Comment: how do you know which belongs to which?

Comment: @JaromandaX my goal is to add the bar on top of the different elements if it is a different category. After each http request for example.

Comment: @madalinivascu there are different http request, so the elements load after each other. The JSON delivers all items from this category and then comes the next one.

Comment: @olivier - sure, but your key will change for each iteration of the for...in loop - so the question is vague

Answer (score 0):

remove the var from the first loop

```js
var values = {pizza: true, box: true, kebab: false};

var key;
for (key in values) {
 console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this before, but `key` has a different value there. Is key out of scope there? How can I solve this? So that key has the correct value?

Comment: what `key` variable??

Comment: what do you mean by different values?

Comment: When i use  `$("#whatToOrder2").append("<div class='box3'>" + key + "</div>");` key has always the value kebab.

Comment: remove the var from the first loop `var key;for (key in values) {` create the value first

Comment: still the same. kebab. kebab is the last element in the array.

Comment: can you paste the values object?

Comment: sure, values looks like this: Object
`{pizza: true, box: true, kebab: false}`

Comment: could it be, because i load the variable in the getJSON function? and key becomes the last value from the last json request?

Comment: does your loop work do you have 3 lines of text in the console?

Comment: i was able to solve it, see above :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
 $.each(values, function(key, val) {

            if (val === true) {

            $.getJSON("js/" + key + "/" + key + ".json", function(data) {
                    $("#whatToOrder2").append("<div class='box3'>" + key + "</div>");
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                        $("#whatToOrder2").append("<div class='box'>" + val.name.toUpperCase() + "<input type='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' value='0' name=" + val.name.replace(/\s/g, '') + " class='css-input2 input-form2' placeholder='Menge'>");

                    });

                 })   

        }

            })
```